# Display Category, Sub Category, Sub Sub Category and further In Hierarchical form in Mongodb and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am new in Nodejs and MongoDB and I am facing a problem to display category, subcategory, and further level. I wanted to show data in the select tag as parent > sub-Category > sub-sub-category > sub-sub-sub-Category.

This is how I store data in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "parent_id": parent_id: 
    "catalogue_id" : catalogue_id,
    "catalogue_name" : abc
}
```

it is not a nested document.

Expected Output: - parent > sub-Category > sub-sub-category > sub-sub-sub-Category

Please help because I am stuck as output is not displaying as expected.

Comment: You can do it with $lookup (here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) (New in version 3.6).

Please share your desired JSON so that I can write an exact query.

Comment: Hi, Jitendra thank you so much for replying my question. I am sharing the concept of JSON structure here. http://snippi.com/s/ui6jvpk .

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/mvde6j2   
Look into it and let me know if it's helpful or what format you desired.

Comment: http://snippi.com/s/b4lbj02 this is the desired format I am implementing.

Comment: @AtitMore did you got solution to your query? I am implementing the same structure and need to know how this can be done.